# Nusphere PhpEd code insight for Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to know if there is a way to use `@var` or `@property` to define code insight in Nusphere PhpEd for `get_instance()` in Codeigniter.

One example would be:

```
// Define @property for Codeigniter object?
class Example
{
    // Define @var for Codeigniter object?
    var $ci;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ci =& get_instance();
    }

    public function test($var)
    {
        $this->ci-> //I want to load Codeigniter insight here
    }
}
```

If I extend the CI_Controller class (`class Example extends CI_Controller`) then I can use `$this->` to get the Codeigniter object ... but I don't want to extend the CI_Controller class (don't want to inherit anything from the parent)

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for;

https://gist.github.com/topdown/1697338

Cheers

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As non-native english speaker, its really hard for me to explain technical documents. This is why i preffer to link to answer. Thanks for sugesstion.